# I have something problems about DropdownButton and items

Tags: flutter

This messages shows up
The argument type 'List<DropdownMenuItem>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem>?

and I have totally no idea..

Plz let me know how to solve this problem.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Add your complete code

Comment: It looks like a null safety issue to me. Can you rewrite your code like : items: getCurrency()!

Comment: Or, add a ? to your List<DropdownMenuItem> function like this: List<DropdownMenuItem>? getCurrency(){}

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-snippet , so that others can test and provide the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the list as not nullable, reason behind the message is from which source may be api or local db data list comes in the form of not NULL. Just remove question Mark.

```
List<DropdownMenuItem> dropList;
```